# Defaultifempty gives me Null values and I want them string " "

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing a linq query in C# and everything works smoothly but when I call this method in the MVC it crashes, it doesn't accept null values I want the null values to be " "

```
var referralDocs = (from d in _dc.ReferralDoctors
                                join mlog in _dc.LogPS.Where(x => x.id_action == 1)
                                on d.ReferralDoctorID equals mlog.id_PS into mlog

                                join _Category in _dc.ReferringDoctorCategories
                                on d.ReferringDoctorsCategory equals _Category.CategoryID into CatGroup
                                from _Category in CatGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                where
                                d.DoctorID == doctorID && d.isDeleted == false && (d.NotificationEmail.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().Contains(search)
                                || d.PracticePhone.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().Contains(search) || d.LastName.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().Contains(search) || d.FirstName.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().Contains(search))
                                select new ReferralDoctorInfo()
                                                        {
                                                            BirthDate = d.BirthDate,
                                                            DoctorID = d.DoctorID,
                                                            FirstName = d.FirstName != null ? d.FirstName.Trim().Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "") : "",
                                                            HasOptOutNews = d.HasOptOutNews,
                                                            isDeleted = d.isDeleted,
                                                            LastName = d.LastName != null ? d.LastName.Trim().Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "") : "",                                                                
                                                            NotificationEmail = d.NotificationEmail != null ? d.NotificationEmail.Trim().Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "") : "",                                                                
                                                            PracticePhone = d.PracticePhone,
                                                            PracticeName = d.PracticeName != null ? d.PracticeName.Trim().Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "") : "",
                                                            ReferralDoctorID = d.ReferralDoctorID,
                                                            lastOptOutDatetime = mlog.Where(x => x.client_id == doctorID && x.id_PS == d.ReferralDoctorID).Max(y => y.date),
                                                            DoctorCategory = _Category 

                                                        });
```

ok I have this in the select:  DoctorCategory = _Category

when I get this object in the MVC the first row of this object has all the values the object should have and works fine but the second row doesn't have values so it gives me nulls which is good since I want to have the ones who doesnt have categories but in that point crashes and therefore I want them to be " "

I want something in DefaultifEmpty or in _Category that allows me to change null values

something like this

```
ReferingDoctorCategory = _Category.Name != null ? _Category.Name : "",
```

the problem with this is that doesn't work for objects so i couldn't use it

Comment: can you post the whole statement?

Comment: Doesn't `DefaultIfEmpty()` accept a single argument? Did you already try `.DefaultIfEmpty(String.Empty)`?

Comment: @Eris I tried that but didn't work I already found an answer thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone wants the same thing as me I found an answer

```
DoctorCategory = _Category ?? new ReferringDoctorCategory()
```

this doesn't change every row that is null to "" but it does put every one empty and in that way the MVC doesn't crash